# Programmatically set test parameters in TestNG xml suite for parallel execution

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops, testng

I'm trying run TestNG suite in parallel mode, but want to change threadCount dynamically depends on external parameters.

If tests number = threadCount (params Number) - I can do it by using TestNG API in this way:

```
            List<String> params = Arrays.asList("1", "2");

            suite.setThreadCount(params.size());
            suite.setParallel(XmlSuite.ParallelMode.TESTS);

            List<XmlTest> xmlTests = suite.getTests();

            for (int i = 0; i < xmlTests.size(); i++) {
                Map<String, String> paramsMap = new HashMap<>();
                paramsMap.put("param", params.get(i));
                xmlTests.get(i).setParameters(paramsMap);
            }
```

But if tests number > threadCount (params Number) I want to set parameters correspondingly to threadCount:

```html
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="TestNG suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">

 <test name="Test 1">
   <parameter name="param" value="1"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.Tests_1">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test 2">
 <parameter name="param" value="2"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.Tests_2">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test 3">
<parameter name="param" value="1"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.Tests_3">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

For example for 2 threadCount and 6 tests set parameters:  1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2;
For 3 threadCount and 5 tests set:  1, 2, 3, 1, 2

How to iterate through tests and set appropriate parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to count index of threadCount:

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < xmlTests.size(); i++) {

            if (j>= params.size()) {
               j = 0;
            }

            Map<String, String> paramsMap = new HashMap<>();
            paramsMap.put("param", params.get(j));
            xmlTests.get(i).setParameters(paramsMap);
            j++;
        }
```